# Do Ratcatchers actually have a superpower to control rats?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, the-suicide-squad-2021

In the movie *The Suicide Squad* (2021), there's Cleo Cazo; a young woman with the code-name **Ratcatcher 2** who's able to control rats. It's mentioned that her father was Ratcatcher 1 and taught her his skills and has already died before the events of the movie. She carries a **handheld device** that enables her to control rats to do her bidding wherever she goes. Bloodsport mentions that it's a superpower.

> **Bloodsport** : Oh, no way. That’s not coming with us.
> **Waller** : She controls rats.
> **Bloodsport** : I know, I caught that. It’s a disgusting superpower.

[[Script]](https://scrapsfromtheloft.com/movies/the-suicide-squad-2021-transcript/)

But every time Cleo controls rats, she seems to be using the device. So does she actually have a superpower, or does she just know how to use that device?

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of perspective? Most people would say that Green Lantern and Stargirl both have superpowers, but all they do is using advanced technology too.

Comment: Iron Man has no powers without his suit, nor does Ant-Man and a high number of other "tech heroes". They are still considered superpowered.

Comment: So What’s your superpower?    Batman: *I’m rich!* 

Comment: They don't elaborate on it in the movie, but I thought she might have some unique insight into operating the device, and maybe not everybody is able to, or even /willing/ too, considering it might easily cover you in rats.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Green Lantern have his willpower and not just anyone can use his ring. As per Stargirl, I don't know much about her. To reword my question, will some random person be able to use it the same way she uses it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Rat Communicator** is similar to the device employed by Ant-Man to control ants. It is a device which allows Ratcatcher and later Ratcatcher 2 to manipulate and train rats.

She is described on [one wiki](https://dcextendeduniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ratcatcher_2#Powers) as having a keen intellect, that allowed her to enhance the device to control far more rats than her father ever could. There is nothing to suggest it is above the norm (like the Thinker).

Without the Rat Communicator she wouldn't be able to control rats, although she would still have her pet rat Sebastian which seems to have above rat intelligence. Possibly a result of so much use with the Rat Communicator.